Video stream freezes after first frame when streaming via webSocket
I'm trying to implement live video streaming using WebSocket in a test HTML page. The backend sends video stream blobs in response to a message "start" , but the video on the frontend only displays the first frame and then freezes. Below is the HTML and JavaScript code I'm using:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Video Streaming</title>
</head>
<body>
<video id="videoPlayer" controls width="500" height="300"></video>
<script>
    const socketServerUrl = "ws://localhost:8080/ws";
    const socket = new WebSocket(socketServerUrl);
    socket.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';

    let mediaSource = new MediaSource();
    const video = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);

    let sourceBuffer;

    mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', () => {
        sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/webm; codecs="vp8"');

        sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', () => {
            if (mediaSource.readyState === 'open' && !sourceBuffer.updating && !video.paused) {
                video.play();
            }
        });

        sourceBuffer.addEventListener('error', (event) => {
            console.log('SourceBuffer error:', event);
        });

        // Handling WebSocket data
        socket.onmessage = (event) => {
            const arrayU8 = new Uint8Array(event.data);
            if (arrayU8.length == 0) {
                return;
            }

            sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(arrayU8);
        };
    });

    socket.onerror = (error) => {
        console.log('WebSocket error:', error);
    };

    socket.onclose = () => {
        console.log('WebSocket connection closed.');
    };

    socket.onopen = () => {
        socket.send(JSON.stringify({"action": "start"}));
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>


I tried to accumulate a blob (around 700KB) on the backend and send it, in this case the video plays for a short time, so the problem is not in the video codec.
It's as if the JavaScript only plays the first blob and then gets stuck. What could be causing the video to freeze after the first frame, and how can I resolve this issue?
PS
the order of sent and received blobs is correct

A number of issues can cause this... likely to do with the segmentation.  But, save yourself a lot of hassle and don't bother with this method at all.  Switch to using straight up HTTP(S), and then just set the URL as your src for your video element.  Web Socket is not needed here.

@Brad Is it about HLS? I studied this issue and concluded that such streaming is suitable for cases when I have a media file on my backend  that I want to stream, but in my case it is a screen capture using ffmpeg

No, the naming is a bit confusing but HLS is unrelated.  I'm talking about simply streaming over HTTP as-is.  It definitely fits your use case.  You're probably taking the STDOUT of FFmpeg now and sending it over Web Socket, yeah?  Instead, just send it as the HTTP response body.  Your HTTP server will stream it in chunked transfer mode and the browser will play it just fine.  Since the Content-Length won't be set, the browser won't try to do anything fancy.  It will just stream it.

Hmm, i should try

I just don't understand how the browser should request the next batch. Let's say the browser sent a POST, received batch in the body, playing and then?

It has to be a GET request.  The browser itself will make the GET request via the video element.  (Ideally, any request data you send can go in the query string.  If it can't, you can always use a POST-then-GET sort of mechanism.)  In any case, there is no inherent batch or chunking... just a continuous stream.  You can pipe your FFmpeg STDOUT directly to the stream being sent to the client.  What are you using server-side?

I tried using HLS, it's working

Alright, well, you can use HLS but you're adding extra overhead, latency, reducing client compatibility, and limiting your codec options for no benefit.  But yes, HLS will work.  HLS would be a good choice if you were streaming to many people.
